# Service from shared module is not visible- Angular 4

Tags: angular

My knowledge on Angular 4 is just on a beginner level. I am trying to provide service from a Shared module in some component as below:

**Project Structure**

```
app
|_ component1
   |_ .css
   |_ .html
   |_ .component.ts
   |_ .module.ts
|_ component2
   |_ //same as above
|_ shared
   |_ messages.components.ts
   |_ number.directive.ts
   |_ shared.module.ts
   |_ validation.service.ts
```

**Problem**

Now I have my **shared.module.ts** as below:

```
//Certain other imports
import { ValidationService } from './validation.service';
@NgModule({
    declarations: [...],
    imports : [....],
    exports : [....],
    providers : [ValidationService]
});

export class SharedModule{}
```

Below is the contents of **validation.service.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
@Injectable()
export class ValidationService {

    static validateText(control) {
           //do something
    }
}
```

Now I am trying to consume the `ValidationService` in `component2` and for that, I've imported `SharedModule` in the module of `component2` as below:

**component2.module.ts**

```
import { SharedModule } from './../shared/shared.module';
//some other imports
@NgModule({
  declarations: [],
  imports: [SharedModule]
})
export class Component2Module { }
```

and **component2.component.ts** is as below:

```
import { SharedModule } from './../shared/shared.module';
//other imports
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './component2.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./component2.component.css']
})
export class Component2Component implements OnInit{
   constructor(){
   }
   ngOnInit() {
    this.sampleForm = new FormGroup({
        sampletxt : new FormControl('', [Validators.required , ValidationService.validateText]), //this method here
    });
   }
}
```

But am not able to use this `ValidationService` unless I import it again in the above file.

My question here is why am not able to use the `ValidationService` without importing it in my `component2` since I've imported `SharedModule` into the component2 module and SharedModule is already providing the `Service`? What am I missing here? This is not possible at all?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adding a service to `imports: []` of an `@NgModule()` registers it to the dependency injection framework (DI).

By listing it in constructor parameters, you instruct DI to pass the service to the constructor, when it creates an instance of your component.

```
constructor(private validationService:ValidationService){
```

for TypeScript to know what `ValidationService` you mean (there could be several in your project or imported modules) you need to add an import to make this clear.

After that you can use it like

```
this.validationService...
```

Comment: Thank you for the brief. One small doubt here. I've static methods within Service. So will it be needed here to add it in constructor?

Comment: Just don't use static methods in services. If you want to use static methods of a service, it's not actually a service and shouldn't be treated like that. There is no need to add such a class to `imports: [...]` or `providers: [...]` anywhere, it just needs a TypeScript import.

Comment: You're welcome. Good idea. Angular went a long way to make a framework that allows everything to be easily testable. Using static methods works agains this big advantage.